# loop a range and then assign value differently based on my current condition

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wish to loop the current input from user.

Example code:

```
hidden_layers = 5

for i in range(hidden_layers):
    weights = {
            "w{}".format(i+1): tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input, ]))

            }
```

How to complete above to get something like my this code?

```
h_layer= 256
h_layer2=256
h_layer3=256
h_layer4=256
h_layer5=256

weights = {
        "w1": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input, h_layer])),
        "w2": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h_layer, h_layer2])),
        "w3": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h_layer2, h_layer3])),
        "w4": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h_layer3, h_layer4])),
        "w5": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h_layer4, h_layer5]))
        "output": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h_layer5, num_output]))
        }
```

I have been thinking since 30mins but cant think of a method.

Comment: what are  `h_layer`, `h_layer2`, `h_layer3` and so on?

Comment: I forgot to mention, its just hidden_layer = h_layer1 .... h_layer5 and its in int form with value 256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the following will help you:

```
hidden_layers = 5
h_layers=[num_input, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256]
weights = {}
for i in range(hidden_layers):
    weights["w{}".format(i+1)] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h_layers[i], h_layers[i+1]]))

weights["output"] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h_layers[-1], num_output]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Haha, didnt realize I can solve it this way.

Comment: Wellcom, glad to help you.